# My custom control in ToolBar

Tags: wpf, coding-style, toolbar

I have a specific control. I want to make style for it when it is placed in ToolBar. I have found how to do it in case of Button, CheckBox and other standard controls, but how I should make it for my control?

Comment: Can you provide an example on how you achieve that for standard control?

Comment: Sure, for example button style for ToolBar will be:

<code>
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now you clarified your question I think I can give you a solution. It looks like you simply need to set the **ItemContainerStyle** of the ToolBar control for your specific user control. First declare the "my" namespace where your specific control is located, then just add something like this:

```
<ToolBar>
    <ToolBar.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
        </Style>
    </ToolBar.ItemContainerStyle>
    <my:MyUserControl/>
</ToolBar>
```

If you wanna add other control types to the ToolBar like the Button you mentioned above, then you will need to define a custom StyleSelector instead that you will set to the ItemContainerStyleSelector property. Here is a pretty good sample of StyleSelector implementation: [Style Selectors](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/common-data-binding-style-selectors.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyleForCustomControl" TargetType="{x:Type NameSpace:CustomControl}">

// Your setter's for your controls go here.

</Style>
```

NameSpace - where your Control is present
CustomControl - Name of your control.

Is this what you want?

**EDIT:**

If you want Style for Toolbar in your control, simply place the style in your UserControl Resources, it will be applied to the Toolbar placed within your control. The scope for this style will be limited to your control and will be hidden outside your control.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
   ....
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: No, it's not. I want style which will be used by ToolBar for my control ;) For standard controls we can use ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey, ToolBar.CheckBoxStyleKey and so on...